# Expected Input to be a List - Errors with Foreach in NetLogo

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I am trying to use the Foreach command to iterate over an agentset.  I am asking each turtle to set the value of a variable to something.  However, I have tried so many syntaxes.  The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
Set all-turtles (turtle-set turtles)

foreach all-turtles [set infoneed one-of infotypes]
```

However, I keep getting the following error: "FOREACH expected input to be a list but got the agentset (agentset, 81 turtles) instead."

How do I fix this?

Thanks,

Brandon

Windows 10//NetLogo 6.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ask turtles [set infoneed one-of infotypes]
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for this, but Ask turtles runs concurrent, which means that all turtles will get the same infotype.  I want each turtle to have a different infotypes.  This is why I was trying to use Foreach...any other suggestions? - Brandon

Comment: @bgreenb1 The turtles are asked in random order but sequentially.  Try it and see.